# Enable/disable checkbox in extjs

Tags: extjs, checkbox, radio-button

I want to enable or disable checkboxes in EXTJS

```
 dockedItems: [{
        xtype: 'toolbar',
        dock: 'top',
        items: [{
            xtype: 'radiofield',
            id: 'all',
            name: 'show',
            boxLabel: 'All',
            checked: true,
            inputValue: 'all'
        }, {
            xtype: 'radiofield',
            id: 'online',
            name: 'show',
            boxLabel: 'Online',
            inputValue: 'online'
        }, {
            xtype: 'radiofield',
            id: 'offline',
            name: 'show',
            boxLabel: 'Offline',
            inputValue: 'offline'
        }, {
            xtype: 'checkboxfield',
            id: 'cb1',
            boxLabel: 'Sometimes',
            checked: true,
            inputValue: 'sometimes'
        }, {
            xtype: 'checkboxfield',
            id: 'cb2',
            boxLabel: 'Always',
            checked: true,
            inputValue: 'always'
        }],
        listeners: {
            change: function (field, newValue, oldValue) {
                var value = newValue.show;
                if (value == 'all') {
                    var cb1 = Ext.getCmp('cb1');
                    var cb2 = Ext.getCmp('cb2');

                    cb1.disable();
                    cb2.disable();
                }
                if (value == 'online') {
                    var cb1 = Ext.getCmp('cb1');
                    var cb2 = Ext.getCmp('cb2');

                    cb1.disable();
                    cb2.disable();
                }
                if (value == 'offline') {

                    var cb1 = Ext.getCmp('cb1');
                    var cb2 = Ext.getCmp('cb2');

                    cb1.enable();
                    cb2.enable();

                }

            }
        }
    }]
```

How can I enable these checkboxes? They should be enabled when the user selects the offline option and disabled when the user selects other option.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple errors I noticed:

The checkbox components cant be referred to by their `id` directly, you could call them with Ext.getCmp('id') though.

Your listener in the example above is attached to the toolbar, which doesn't have a `change` event. You need to attach it to the radio instead.

Actually, if you only want the checkboxes enabled when the 'offline' radio is filled then I would recommend adding a `handler` config to the 'offline' radio with a function to enable or disable the checkboxes depending on what value this radio is changed to. For example, this works:

```
dockedItems: [{
    xtype: 'toolbar',
    dock: 'top',
    items: [{
        xtype: 'radiofield',
        id: 'all',
        name: 'show',
        boxLabel: 'All',
        checked: true,
    }, {
        xtype: 'radiofield',
        id: 'online',
        name: 'show',
        boxLabel: 'Online',
        inputValue: 'online',
    }, {
        xtype: 'radiofield',
        id: 'offline',
        name: 'show',
        boxLabel: 'Offline',
        inputValue: 'offline',
        handler: function(field, value) {
            if (value) {
                Ext.getCmp('cb1').enable();
                Ext.getCmp('cb2').enable();
            } else {
                Ext.getCmp('cb1').disable();
                Ext.getCmp('cb2').disable();        
            }            
        }
    }, {
        xtype: 'checkboxfield',
        id: 'cb1',
        boxLabel: 'Sometimes',
        checked: true,
        inputValue: 'sometimes',
        disabled: true
    }, {
        xtype: 'checkboxfield',
        id: 'cb2',
        boxLabel: 'Always',
        checked: true,
        inputValue: 'always',
        disabled: true
    }]
}],
```

I suggest using `handler` config (as above) and not having a listener on the `change` event.

If you add a `change` listener it will override the *default* `change` handler used by ExtJS internally to deselect the other radio fields in the same name group. E.g. with a `change` listener on the 'offline' radio, when you select it, 'all' will remain selected.

In other words... just copy the example above and all will be well.

Comment: When I set the `checked: true` and `disabled: true` for a checkbox and submit the form, the server does not receive the checkbox parameter value as `on`. It is omitted from the post params. How can I use both disabled and a checked value for a checkbox and get it as a parameter on submit?

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following you need to set ids for the checkboxs to look them up in this example:

```
 if (value == 'offline') {
            var cb1 = Ext.getCmp('cbox1');//look up by given checkbox ids
            var cb2 = Ext.getCmp('cbox2');//look up by given checkbox ids

cb1.enable();
cb2.enable(); 

online 
  }
else {
        var cb1 = Ext.getCmp('cbox1');//look up by given checkbox ids
            var cb2 = Ext.getCmp('cbox2');//look up by given checkbox ids

cb1.disable();
cb2.disable(); 
}
```

Comment: haha i think i did something wrong. My radiobuttons are disabled and my checkboxes are enabled by default :)

Answer (score 0):

A standard approach to enable / disable checkbox in ExtJS is to set configuration parameters `disable: true` or `disable: false` when creating component.

But as for ExtJS 4.2 - it has some inconvenience. Disabling or setting checkbox to readOnly makes component look very transparent. In classic framework design and maybe some others you won't even see a tick in the box if it's disabled or set to readOnly. As if it were empty.

The best solution we found is to create a project global css class for all ExtJS elements of this type. It shifts to a better tick sign in standard framework theme image and adds some opacity:

```
.x-form-readonly .x-form-checkbox {
  background-image: url(/extjs/resources/ext-theme-classic/images/form/checkbox.gif);
  opacity: 0.4;
}
```